# I have a device reporting left handed coordinate angle and magnitude, how do I represent that as a line on the screen from the center?

Tags: c++, math, graphics, embedded

The device I am using generates vectors like this;
[image]

How do I translate polar (angle and magnitude) from a left handed cordinate to a cartesian line, drawn on a screen where the origin point is the middle of a screen?

I am displaying the line on a wt32-sc01 screen using c++. There is a tft.drawline function but its references are normal pixel locations. In which case 0,0 is the upper left corner of the screen.

This is what I have so far (abbreviated)

```
....
int screen_height = tft.height();
int screen_width = tft.width();
// Device can read to 12m and reports in mm
float zoom_factor = (screen_width / 2.0) / 12000.0;
int originY = (int)(screen_height / 2);
int originX = (int)(screen_width / 2);
// Offset is for screen scrolling. No screen offset to start
int offsetX = 0;
int offsetY = 0;
...
// ld06 holds the reported angles and distances.
Coord coord = polarToCartesian(ld06.angles[i], ld06.distances[i]);
drawVector(coord, WHITE);

Coord polarToCartesian(float theta, float r) {
  // cos() and sin() take radians
  float rad = theta * 0.017453292519;
  Coord converted = {
    (int)(r * cos(rad)),
    (int)(r * sin(rad))
  };
  return converted;
}

void drawVector(Coord coord, int color) {
  // Cartesian relative the center of the screen factoring zoom and pan
  int destX = (int)(zoom_factor * coord.x) + originX + offsetX;
  int destY = originY - (int)(zoom_factor * coord.y) + offsetY;
  // From the middle of the screen (origin X, origin Y) to destination x,y
  tft.drawLine( originX, originY, destX, destY, color);
}
```

I have something drawing on the screen, but now I have to translate between a left handed coordinate system and the whole plane is rotated 90 degrees. How do I do that?

Comment: This brings back memories. I learned these formulas in high school. Don't they teach them any more?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I wouldn't know I haven't been in high school in 4 decades.

Comment: That's close enough to my own timeline. And I know these things were taught back then. So, what's the stumbling block here? 0 degrees appears to be `pi/4` in radians, and the formula for translating 0-360 to radians is, what, the first one that's taught in trig class? Mission accomplished?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik The rotation is reversed, that's the problem.

Comment: So? Pop quiz: there are four elementary arithmetical operations. Addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. That is: one of them, when operated on the starting degree and the theta, will solve this difficult problem? Meaning: `pi/2 (?) theta` (in radians) calculates the "reversed" rotation, producing the radian degree based on the "normal" rotation from 0 degrees (correcting my earlier mistake, it's pi/2). There's only four possibilities. If unsure, all of them can be tried, one by one, until the one that works is identified.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you're right, there was no reason I couldn't work that out for myself. Thank you.

Comment: This is a maths question, not a programming question.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, your coordinate system is with x pointing to the right and the y to the bottom and you used the formula for the standard math coordinate system where y is pointing up so multiplying your sin by -1 should do the trick (if it doesn't, try multiplying random things by -1, it often works for this kind of problems).

Answer (score 0):

I assuming (from your image) your coordinate system has x going right y going up angle going from y axis clockwise and `(0,0)` is also center of your polar coordinates and your goniometrics accept radians then:

```cpp
#include <math.h>
float x,y,ang,r;
const float deg = M_PI/180.0;
// ang = <0,360> // your angle
// r >= 0        // your radius (magnitude)

x = r*sin(ang*deg);
y = r*cos(ang*deg);
```